# 60's or earlier probably "young adult" story about a community sent into the future by a nuclear accident

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I know exactly when I read this story, in the spring of 1968, when I was in Germany to improve my german. Of course it could have been written any time before.  I actually read it in german. But I was not really so fluent in german, so I deliberately chose to read this rather short book with the rationale that, **being a translation from english**, it would have shorter sentences. And it worked, I managed to read it to the end.

I'm almost sure there was only this story in the book, but it was a short one, not a novel, just a novella and not a very long one at that. In hindsight, I would say it was for "Young Adult", but of course I **was** a young adult then.

The beginning was perhaps inspired by Asimov's "Pebble In the Sky". There was an incident in a nuclear power plant, and a whole community (not a big city, but a town, not too small) was sent into the future. But the Earth they reach is empty. I think the power plant came with them, because I think they still have electric power. That's how they realise that noone else is there because they don't receive any broadcast from anywhere. They use their own radio station to contact other towns or cities but get no immediate answer.
But after a few days one spaceship, or maybe more, land near them. Their calls for help have been heard. Out of the spaceship came all kind of species, many alien ones, but also humans. The humans are dominant but the others are not slaves or anything, just like "junior partners". At first the people from the past are very afraid of the strange-looking aliens, but soon find them more friendly than the humans of the future.

Another common point with "Pebble In the Sky" is that these humans from space are not very warm for the Earthlings from the past. The reader at some point finds out that in the past, the humans that left Earth to become "Spacers" despised the ones who stayed on Earth. There was some bitter happenings. And mankind died on Earth. Even though these people from the past were before space travel and thus ancestors to all humans, the spacer humans from the future despise them.

Sure, they came to help, not to kill, but it appears that they want to keep them from modern technology, just help them to barely survive on the empty planet. It is the other species from space who join with the humans from the past. I don't remember any fight or bloodshed. It is just a matter of groups of influence, the spacer humans from the future finding everyone else against them and having to give in and give equal status to all.

Well, this is if I remember the end correctly. The elements which are really remember is the aliens and the humans form the past joining forces against the humans from space. I don't remember violence, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Some elements of this share similarities with Vernor Vinge's Bobble/Across Realtime sequence, especially the final book *Marooned in Realtime*.

Comment: *City at World's End* by Edmond Hamilton. Please check out [these old answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bstory-identification%5d%20hamilton%20city%20end) and if you agree we can close this question as a dupe without having to post another answer!

Comment: The plot of Hamilton's yarn differs in some ways from your recollection, but I think it must be the same story. You can read it here: https://archive.org/details/Startling_Stories_v21n03_1950-07/page/n1

Comment: Marooned in Realtime was written decades after I read that book.

Comment: City at World's End  has the same **beginning**. But none of the answers speaks of aliens more friendly than humans. I'd have to find the story to check.

Comment: A German translation of *City at World's End*, titled *SOS—die Erde erkaltet* was published in 1952 and reissued in 1956, 1962, and 1972. Maybe one of these covers will ring a bell: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1386523

Comment: Well,  I just got the full text there are several similarities. The beginning, clearly, and an mix of huamn and aliens visitors. But there is only one alien among a total of four visitors from outer space, and I remember a whole crowd of visitors, with a majority of aliens. But maybe this is a false memory ? I also checked the german translations, and the covers don't ring a bell. The aliens on the cover in my memory looked more alien than a bear. But that might also be a false memory

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. There are many similarities, but it does not really fit. The fact there there were three german editions before 1968 would indicate it is the same story, but somehow I am not yet convinced. I only went rapidly over the full text. The first to arrive were three humans from Vega and the bear-like Capellan, I remember more aliens. But there is also a Spican, maybe I missed later arrivals. I'll have to do more checks. But I think my book was shorter than City at World's End.

Comment: @user14111 OK, so the other aliens come out on chapter 11, among two score of members of the crew. That is indeed my book, now, I recognise it. It is indeed a duplicate.